# How can I use clap "subcommands" based on flags?

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, clap

I have an rsync-like rust program. The main user interface is something like `program src dest`.

It needs to invoke itself on another machine over ssh in order to read or write files. This is an implementation detail, and I don't want to *really* expose it as a subcommand, and risk `src` being misinterpreted.

I'd like to run these implementation details using flags.

- `program --read file` would start writing the file to stdout.
- `program --write file` would start writing stdin to the file.
- `program ./local user@remote:remote/file` would write `./local` to the stdin of `ssh user@remote program --write remote/file`.
- `program user@remote:remote/file ./local` would write the stdout of `ssh user@remote program --read file` to `./local`.

I've tried using the clap derive API's `group` feature for its `ArgGroup`s. The [derive tutorial example](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/_derive/_tutorial/chapter_3/index.html#argument-relations) flattens structs.

```rust
use std::ffi::OsString;
use clap::{Args, Parser};

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
struct RsyncExample {
    #[command(flatten)]
    inner_op: ImplOperation,

    #[command(flatten)]
    transfer: Option<FileTransfer>,
}

#[derive(Args, Clone, Debug)]
#[group(required = false, multiple = false, conflicts_with = "FileTransfer")]
struct ImplOperation {
    #[arg(long)]
    read: bool,
    #[arg(long)]
    write: bool,
}

#[derive(Args, Clone, Debug)]
struct FileTransfer {
    from: OsString,
    to: OsString,
}

fn main() {
    let cli = RsyncExample::parse();
    println!("{cli:?}");
}
```

While the following will rightly disallow specifying both `--read --write`, and disallow `--read file1 file2`, the error message is a bit confusing. It still specifies `FROM` and `TO`.

```
$ cargo run -- --read from
error: the argument '--read' cannot be used with:
  <FROM>
  <TO>

Usage: blktrans --read <FROM> <TO>

For more information, try '--help'.
```

And even with this, I can't figure out how to allow a single file with those flags.

I have considered linking to this program with a different name, and dispatching based on `argv[0]`. But I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: What if you use `read: Option<OsString>` instead of `read: bool`?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain I understand what you're trying to do, but it feels like `RsyncExample` should be an `enum` instead of a `struct`, no?

Comment: @Yoric philosophically, yes. But how would I then make clap parse that in the way I described?